# SOAPUI 4.5.1 Could Not Generate DH keypair

Tags: java, soapui

I'm running SOAPUI 4.5.1 on Windows 7.  I'm using the stand-alone ZIP version.  It tells me that it's using JRE 1.7.0_03 in the command shell when I run the startup .bat file.

My original configuration was installed using the .exe.  It ran fine under JDK 1.6.0_51.  Then I installed JDK 1.7.0_45-b18 on my machine and I started getting this exception whenever I submitted a request:

```
Tue Dec 17 15:06:49 EST 2013:ERROR:javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
```

This is the root cause:

```
   Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)
```

It's a [well-known problem](http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?t=2931), but I haven't been successful at implementing a solution.

The .exe install uses bcprov-jdk15-144.jar.  I went to [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html), downloaded bcprov-jdk15-150.jar, added it to the /lib directory; no joy.

I uninstalled JDK 7; no joy.

I uninstalled the .exe and put the stand-alone ZIP version on my machine; no joy.

Google suggests that telling SOAPUI to use the latest JDK will solve the problem

I don't know how to tell SOAPUI to use the latest JDK 1.7.0_45-b18 instead of JRE 1.7.0_03.  I looked at the soapui-settings.xml, but no joy.

Any advice on how to remedy this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified the bin/soapui.bat to use my JAVA_HOME java.exe rather than the bundled JRE:

```
rem if exist "%SOAPUI_HOME%..\jre\bin" goto SET_BUNDLED_JAVA

if exist "%JAVA_HOME%" goto SET_SYSTEM_JAVA
```

By changing my JAVA_HOME, I can make this work with either JDK 6 or 7.

I'm still mystified as to why it won't work with the bundled JRE, but I'm satisfied with this solution.

Answer (score 3):

SoapUI contains it own jre in SmartBear/SoapUI/jre/
I just download jre1.8.0_45 and replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Four years later...

All I needed to do was to apply the JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files from the current version of Java that was bundled with Soap UI.  The steps were:

1. Download the policy files from [Oracle - Java 7 for example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html)
2. Extract the 2 .jar files from above, into the relevant **\jre\lib\security** folder, (replacing the existing files)

   - I was using the jre bundled with Soap UI for windows, so in my case the path was C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.3.0\jre\lib\security
3. Restart Soap UI & enjoy the goodness

Answer (score 0):

Had the issue up until SoapUI 5.3. An upgrade to 5.4 did the trick.